# Is it still an even function if I replace $y$ with $-y$

Tags: functions, terminology

I have a function, say, $x=y^2$ which is of the form $x=f(y)$  so if I replace $y$ with $-y$ and I get $f(y) = f(-y)$ can I still call it an Even function?

The reason I'm asking this is because everywhere I see, the definition is "if you replace $x$ with $-x$ and you get $f(x) = f(-x)$ then it's an even function" instead of "if you replace the independent variable of the function with it's additive inverse and the function remains unchanged then it's an even function"

I feel the former definition is a bit more specific, hence this question arises.

Comment: Did you think about which is the independent variable in your first equation? As you say, ".. is of the form..." in your first sentence. The variable can be anything whatever, x,y,z, potato chip. It doesn't matter what you call it. You could think of this as a function of x if you take the root, if that helps, it is not the same function then, and also breaks the rule, but it's a different function, or more to your question swap the x and y, then f(x)=y=x^2.

Comment: I must admit that I don't see a difference between the two definitions. Could you explain ? By the way, I have never seen definitions stating "replace $y$ with $-y$", this is not what you do.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was asking, whether the independent variable has to be $x$ only or can it be anything else too? What if my independent variable is $y$ in say, $x=f(y)$ if I strictly stick to definition then I'd have to prove $f(y) = f(-y)$ . The difference between the the two definitions is more related to graphically. But nevermind thnx. Mark Bennet answered exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @William if $\text{chip}(\text{potato}) = \text{chip}(\text{-potato}) \quad \forall \text{potato}$ then $\text{chip}$ is an even function of $\text{potato}$. You can replace $\text{chip}$ and $\text{potato}$ with whatever labels you like.

Comment: @gandalf61 I believe it should be $\forall \text{potato} \in D_{\text{chip}}$ haha learning math for MSE is never boring lol

Comment: Huh. I just googled for "if you replace $x$ with $-x$ and you get $f(x) = f(-x)$" and got nothing even close to an exact match. In what "everywhere" have you seen this formulation? (And yes, I realize you were deliberately paraphrasing. But when you paraphrase math you don't completely understand, the chances of paraphrasing it _wrong_ are quite large.)

Comment: @DavidK Yes sir! ;_;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can say is that $x$ is an even function of $y$

If $f(x)=f(-x)$ then $f(x)$ is an even function of $x$. It doesn't matter that the letter is $x$, but it does matter what the independent variable is.

For example, suppose $f(x)=x^4+x^2$, this is an even function of $x$.

But if I put $z=x^2$ then $g(z)=z^2+z$ is not an even function of $z$ (even though  $g(x^2)=f(x)$)

Comment: You shouldn't write $f(z)=z^2+z$, which is wrong, but $g(z)=z^2+z$. Then $g(x^2)=f(x)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have changed to make it clearer - thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is said *even* when

$$\forall x, f(x)=f(-x).$$

There is no ambiguity in this statement.

---

$$\forall x, x^2=(-x)^2$$

is true, so the square function is even.

$$\forall x, x+1=-x+1$$

is false, so the "plus one"function is not even.